# SSL/TLS Certificate Validation Issue with AWS Network Load Balancer and OpenSearch VPC endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nlb

I am facing an issue with SSL/TLS certificate validation when trying to access my AWS OpenSearch cluster through an AWS Network Load Balancer (NLB). Here are the details of my setup:

- I have configured an NLB to terminate SSL/TLS.
- I have associated a valid SSL certificate with the NLB.
- The NLB forwards traffic to an OpenSearch VPC endpoint.
- I can't access the OpenSearch cluster via HTTPS,  the SSL certificate is not being validated.

It's important to note that the SSL certificate I'm using properly works with other services, indicating that the certificate itself is valid and correctly configured.

The problem is that I **can** access the OpenSearch cluster via HTTPS  when I don't provide a valid SSL certificate (i.e., no SSL certificate) in the browser

I have double-checked the certificate installation on the NLB, the cipher suites, and the SSL/TLS protocols. Everything appears to be configured correctly.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or can you suggest what might be causing this problem? Any guidance on troubleshooting this SSL certificate validation issue would be greatly appreciated.